# Jquery - appending each element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, csv, html-table

My Code:

This is my CSV file:

```
Item, Quantity, Price;
LED, 100, $10;
PIR, 1, $5;
DS18B20, 10, $5;
```

This is my jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "data.csv",
    success: function(result) {
      var data = result;
      var arr = data.split(";");
      var len = arr.length - 1;
      var a = 0;
      var b = 0;
      while (a < len) {
        var orr = arr[a].split(",");
        var err = orr.length;
        b = 0;
        while (b < err) {
          if (a == 0) {
            $("#table").find('table')
              .append($('<tr>')
                .append($('<th>' + orr[b] + '</th>'))
              );
            b = b + 1;
          } else if (a > 0) {
            $("#table").find('table')
              .append($('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>' + orr[b] + '</td>'))
              );
            b = b + 1;
          };
        };
        a = a + 1;
      };
    }
  });
});
```

This code puts every element into a TR tag and I want it to put all the elements in one line in a TR tag.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>tables</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="myjquery.js">  
</head>
<body>
<div id="table">
<table>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you make it readable? `#IndentationFail`

Comment: Can you replicate the issue somehow?

Comment: Amend your code to create the `tr` in the outer `while` and append `td` elements to that `tr` in the inner `while`.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I'm sorry about the indentation i'm new to jquery

Comment: @TechDinoKing Yea, just try to indent, which is a good coding practise. It's **not** related to jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i Don't understand...Can you please post the code as an answer.

Comment: @TechDinoKing Why don't you start with posting your HTML?

Comment: @TechDinoKing: Why not accepting my answer? What your expected was provided. If not, tell me what...

Comment: @FadhlyPermata Yes, it works i didn't try running the the code because i didn't understand it...I think i'll just have learn more Jquery, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var csv = 'Item, Quantity, Price;' +
          'LED, 100, $10;' +
          'PIR, 1, $5;' +
          'DS18B20, 10, $5;';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var arrCsv = csv.split(';');
  var result = '';
  
  $.each(arrCsv, function(key, val) {
    if (val.trim() !== '') {
      var arrCols = val.split(',');
    
      result += '<tr>';
    
      $.each(arrCols, function(idx, value){
        result += (key == 0 ? '<th>' : '<td>') + value + (key == 0 ? '</th>' : '</td>');
      });
    
      result += '</tr>';
    }
  });
  
  $('table').append(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" width="100%">
</table>
```